# How to perform reset of textfield using actionsheet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I want to reset the textfields of myview to empty when an actionsheet destructive button is pressed. Done button calls the actionsheet.
This is my actionsheet:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *sheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:sender cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Reset" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

And is used this method to reset:

```
- (void)sheet:(UIActionSheet *)sheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
        self.textf1.text = @"";
    }
}
```

But Nothing is happening.

[image]

[image]

Comment: replace `delegate:sender` to `delegate:self` that's why delegates are not getting call, once you done just set all textFiled to `.text= @""`. i hope it will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `delegate:sender` to `delegate:self` that's why delegates

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

are not getting call also update the delegate function, once you done just set all textFiled to `.text= @""`. i hope it will work

Also posted as Comment earlier.

Comment: @hereAll Down voters warm welcome to you but it will be good if you give some review comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of issues:

Change this line:

```
if (buttonIndex == 0)
```

to:

```
if (buttonIndex == sheet.destructiveButtonIndex)
```

You also need to pass `self` as the delegate instead of `sender`.

```
UIActionSheet *sheet= [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Options" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Reset" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
```

And the name of the delegate method matters. You need:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)sheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

See the docs for `UIActionSheet`. There are specific properties to get various button indexes. Use those over hardcoding index numbers.

Also note that `UIAlertView` is deprecated. You should be using `UIAlertController` unless you need to support iOS 7.

Comment: if (buttonIndex == sheet.destructiveButtonIndex) gave error of "sheet is undeclared" although i i declared it, don't know why

Comment: Perhaps you renamed the parameter to `actionSheet` from your original `sheet`.

Comment: Oh ya, thats y, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

***delegate method you are using is worng***

Please make your delegate to self

```
delegate:self
```

and Use this method

```
 - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      ////check index and empty all textfields

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set self as the delegate, and I think the new UIAlertController is more convenience to use, without any delegate:

```
 UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Action Sheet" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];

 UIAlertAction *reset = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Reset" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
     self.textf1.text = @"";
 }];

actionSheet.actions = @[reset, cancel];

[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    UIActionSheet *sheet;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtText;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

//Button click 

- (IBAction)OpenActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    sheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"ActionSheetDemo" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Reset" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
}
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex==0)
    {
        _txtText.text=@"";
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: 1) Don't post code-only answers. Explain what was wrong and how your answer solves the problem. 2) What's the point of your answer? How does it improve on the other 4 answers posted long before yours? 3) Why add all of the other unneeded code in your answer?